# How to create video (as file MP4, Avi, etc) from sequence of image byte[] in Xamarin.Forms (.Net Standard 2.0/2.1)?

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, ffmpeg, .net-standard-2.0, .net-standard-2.1

I am working on a Xamarin.Forms (.net standard 2.1) application. I have to convert the sequence of images to video. I have a byte array of each image.

I tried with FFMPEG, FFMPEG.AutoGen. But I am getting a platform not supported error on the "FFmpeg.sws_getContext" method. So, Is there any way to convert the sequence of images to one video?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can play the image array in the duration by using **Animation**.

For example

```
var animation = new Animation(v => {

       foreach (var imageAsBytes in imageArray)

       image.Source = ImageSource.FromStream(() => new MemoryStream(imageAsBytes));

}, 1, 5);
```

Of course you can use MVVM and set source in ViewModel .

Comment: Thank You @Lucas Zhang, I want to generate the file (like AVI, mp4). I don't need to show.

Comment: Check https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ByteScout.ImageToVideoSDKforNET